# How to export Python output to Microsoft Access?

Tags: python, database, ms-access, database-connection

I want to **export** the **output** of my **python** **file** **to microsoft access**, I tried several ways but couldn't figure out yet.

The output of this code:

```
 import os


def getFolderSize(folder):
    total_size = os.path.getsize(folder)
    try:
        for item in os.listdir(folder):
            itempath = os.path.join(folder, item)
        
            if os.path.isdir(itempath):
                total_size += getFolderSize(itempath)
            elif os.path.isfile(itempath):
                total_size += os.path.getsize(itempath)
    except Exception:
       print("ex")
    return total_size
a=os.listdir("D:\\")
for folder in a:
    if os.path.isdir("D:\\"+folder):
        print("Folder name: ",folder," size: ",getFolderSize("D:\\"+folder)/(1024*1024*1024), "gb")
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: sorry, done added the code

Comment: Your `for` loop could generate a list of tuples, which you could use to create a pandas DataFrame, and then you could use `to_sql()` along with [sqlalchemy-access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/) to upload the DataFrame to the Access database.